# How to check wifi/cellular connection enable/disbale from settings

Tags: android

I have a use-case in my application, that I need to detect whether the network wifi or cellular is explicitly disabled by the user in settings.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect whether the cellular or wifi is active,

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context): Boolean {
    val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
    val capabilities = manager?.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.activeNetwork) ?: return false

    return capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
}
```

You can modify this function to detect if either of them is inactive and then act accordingly.